# Difference between <html:hidden> and <input type="hidden"> on IE11

Tags: javascript, spring, internet-explorer-11, jsp-tags

I have come across a strange issue which seems to be browser related(IE9 and lower vs. IE11), but would like to know why the strange behavior.

Issue Description:I use a spring framework and use its related taglibs to retrieve data on my JSP. There is a variable called index which I retrieve from the form and it used to be retrieved in the following manner.

```
<html:hidden property="index" name="pdmAcctSuppressForm" />
```

Value for the above variable namely `index` was accessed in a javascript using the following code snippet.

```
var index = document.getElementById("index").value;
```

The javascript seems to work as expected and retrieves the actual value in all IE browsers until IE9, but seems to fail to work on IE11. `document.getElementById("index")` returns invalid on IE11.

**Solution:** The problem has been resolved by changing the above mentioned taglib implementation from 
`<html:hidden property="index" name="pdmAcctSuppressForm" />`

to

`<input type="hidden" name="pdmAcctSuppressForm" value="${pdmAcctSuppressForm.index}" id="index"/>`

I would like to know what has been changed on IE11 which renders the implementation unusable and also if the solution I have quoted is the right and efficient one.

Answer (score 2):

> The javascript seems to work as expected and retrieves the actual value in all IE browsers until IE9, but seems to fail to work on IE11.
>   
> ...
>   
> I would like to know what has been changed on IE11 which renders the implementation unusable and also if the solution I have quoted is the right and efficient one.

You should have had that problem with IE8 as well. Through IE7, IE had a bug: It found elements using `getElementById` that **didn't have the `id` you asked for**, but did have a `name` that matched. That is, in IE8 and earlier:

```
<input name="foo">
```

...would be found by `document.getElementById("foo")`.

This was a bug (although for a while Microsoft called it a feature, and documented it), and it was fixed.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*...by any other name, would smell as sweet*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html)

Comment: @Crowder: The problem you mentioned on your blog seems relevant when there are duplicates i.e.. which share the same name and/or id. But in my case there is only one index field in the JSP. Still the same issue??

Comment: @sandy: Doesn't matter whether there are duplicates. The issue is that your old markup was creating an element with a `name` and not an `id`. Old IE was finding it, because it's silly enough to find elements with a matching `name` rather than a matching `id`. Newer IE fixes that bug, and will only find the element if it has the correct `id`.

Comment: Coming to IE8, we migrated from IE7 onto IE9, hence we didn't face the issue, but somehow it worked well on IE9 too.

Comment: @sandy: Perhaps a compatibilty setting.

Comment: The <html:hidden> tag doesn't have an id field. In my implementation I have loads of such implementation. Do I go about changing all the tags now? Such a mess IE is at times.

Comment: @sandy: You don't *have* to use `getElementById`. IE8 and later (and all modern browsers) have `querySelector`. So you could do `var index = document.querySelector("input[name=index]").value;`

Comment: @Crowder: Awesome, Thanks for the input. I will implement your suggestion and post updates.